# Pandas: sort according to a row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this (with labels on rows and columns):

```
    0 1 2 3

0   1 1 0 0
1   0 1 1 0
2   1 0 1 0
-1  5 6 3 2
```

I would like to order the columns according to the last row (and then drop the row):

```
    0 1 2 3

0   1 1 0 0
1   1 0 1 0
2   0 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.argsort` to get the order, then `iloc` to rearrange columns and drop rows:

```
df.iloc[:-1, np.argsort(-df.iloc[-1])]
```

Output:

```
   1  0  2  3
0  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  1  0
2  0  1  1  0
```